# Traceroute failing on a distant server

Tags: networking, traceroute

I am having trouble running traceroute to a distant server.

This fails from my live server.
[traceroute fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjzIQ.png)

However, this works from my test server. (Both hosted by the same company)
[traceroute success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxJGO.png)

To me, this suggests a routing issue somewhere in the deepest darkest Internet.

Is this the case? Any ideas how I go about getting this fixed?

Comment: Have you contacted your hosting company about this? Assuming the live server itself doesn't have any matching firewall rules.

Comment: yes, they suggested it was a routing path issue and to do trace in the opposite direction.
I am waiting to hear back more information about the remote server.